# Getting :"Artifactory response: 308 Permanent Redirect" when using JFROG CLI tool on linux

Tags: jfrog-cli

I'm trying to copy a package from one location to another using the jfrog cli, something like:

**jfrog rt cp 1st-place/app/1.0.123/ 2nd-place/**

And I'm getting the error:

```
[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Error] Artifactory response: 308 Permanent Redirect
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

The app url did not changed on the webi. It used to work just fine a while ago. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

We just dealt with a similar issue yesterday with publishing NPM packages to Artifactory. For us, the issue turned out to be http vs https. Not sure what your config is set to, but might be worth checking that it's set to https.